# C#: calculate numeric types maximum size range

Tags: c#, math

I want to write a code that gets the maximum sizes of numeric types in c#.

However I don't know the formula on how to calculate the maximum positive number and negative number.

for example:

int32 is a signed 32 bit integer, and its `size range` is `-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647` now I want to figure out how to calculate the value of size range. I just want to know how to get the value if there is a formula or samples will be helpful. Thanks so much and sorry for asking a dummy question for Math wizards out there.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe something like `2^31 - 1` where `^` means "power" or "exponentiate" for the maximum value.

Comment: @vcsjones let me try the formula

Comment: where did you get the value of 2 and 31?

Comment: Probably the most obvious way to express `int.MinValue` as a calculation is `1 << 31`, and `MaxValue` is just one less than that.

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. In the context of C#, there is no need to calculate the range. You can use e.g. `int.MinValue` and `int.MaxValue` to get those values. If you need a more general solution, where you actually do the computation, then you first need to figure out what the binary format of the value is. The usual format for integers, in .NET and elsewhere, is 2's complement; knowing that, and the number of bits, you can calculate the range as `[-(2^(b-1)), 2^(b-1)-1]` where `b` is the number of bits. Other numeric formats are more complicated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144732/discussion-between-harold-and-jdweng).

Comment: No.  I want to let everybody know the truth.  If you think I'm wrong read the Wiki page : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: @jdweng you are the one disagreeing with the wiki here, if you're so sure about this you should edit it

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with Wiki.  You are.  Wiki says : −(2N − 1) to +(2N − 1 − 1)  which is 0xFFFF to 0x7FFF.   As you can see 0x8000 is missing.  The article doesn't specifically say that 0x8000 is not used.

Comment: @jdweng −(2^(N − 1)) = 0x8000 if we stick with 16 bits

Comment: The ordering is actually {0x8001, 0x8002,..,0xFFFF,0x0000,0x0001,...,0x7FFF}.  The point is there is same number of positive and negative numbers no including zero.  If 0x8000 was included there would not be the same number of positive and negative numbers.

Comment: @jdweng sure, including 0x8000 makes it unbalanced in a sense. That might be an argument for banning it, but that doesn't mean that it's *actually banned* - C# doesn't ban it, Java doesn't, the wikipedia page about two's complement doesn't, you're not the only person to ban the value with only the sign bit set but it's clearly not a universal rule. Eg the range of `short` in C# and Java is {0x8000 .. 0xFFFF, 0x0000 .. 0x7FFF}, as would be expected when the most negative integer is not banned.

Comment: When you design a microprocessor there are carry-in, carry-out, overflow, and underflow errors that you design into the microprocessor.  So the higher level languages must allow for testing the errors.  It doesn't mean that from the mathematical view that negative zero is a valid number.  If you have 0x7FFFF + 1 you get an overflow error in 32 bits and 0x8000.  You now have an error condition, not negative zero.  If you have a 64 bit integer then you get 0x00008000 which is not negative zero.  Negative zero in 64 is 0x80000000.

Comment: @jdweng the math works out fine if you allow 0x8000. In fact it works out much better than if you ban it, because banning it creates a "hole". If you allow 0x8000 the whole equivalence with unsigned arithmetic and thus Z/2^16Z (or whatever power) works. If you ban it, even things such as `(x - y) + y = x` are not, not even if looking only at cases without overflow, since `x - y` can legitimately be the most negative integer.

Comment: The math causes exceptions in a microprocessor.  The programming languages allow much more freedom so modeling can be performed.  It doesn't mean the results are valid.

Comment: @jdweng 2's complement arithmetic is unsigned arithmetic with a different interpretation. That's the point. Anything that is valid in unsigned arithmetic is automatically valid in signed arithmetic, and that includes anything to do with the most negative integer which is not a special number when interpreting it unsigned. There are no exceptions, there is absolutely no reason for them to exist (it's the same circuit as for unsigned arithmetic!). All results are valid, even in case of signed overflow. I hope you're just trolling at this point, otherwise you're dangerously wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
var x = int.MaxValue;
```

Will give you the max. Same for all primitive math types ie: decimal, double etc...